# Django, io module for deserialization of data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework documentation, there is process of deserialization as mention below

```
import io

stream = io.BytesIO(content)
data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
```

here `content` is a JSON object.

Why can't we directly deserialize data as `data = JSONParser().parse(content)`, when I did that in localmachine it raised error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: What is the **`type(content)`**? a `str` ?

Comment: <class 'bytes'>, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ this is the documentation link

Comment: I hope this image may help you to understand how to make it work, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz875.png)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that

Comment: Serialization in REST framework is a two-phase process[drf docs]:
1. Serializers marshal between complex types like model instances, and
python primitives.
2. The process of marshalling between python primitives and request and
response content is handled by parsers and renderers.

Answer (score 1):

it is because of request.body return data in bytes(<class 'bytes'>) and
**data =JSONParser().parse(stream)** parse function take  <class '_io.BytesIO'> object as a    arguments if u pass <class 'bytes'> object then it show this error AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slmb6.png)

Comment: Code typed into the answers is preferable to pictures of code: ["copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)